# Unable to see css in jenking html report

Tags: css, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

At the moment jenkins exports the html reports through publishReports but I am unable to see all the colors and so on, my question is if it's possible to insert this command:

`System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")`

through a scripted pipeline and how, because I do not have access in script console or the settings of jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only way to act on jenkins "System" is to use the groovy script console. From a pipeline you could do an API call.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42470125

However the simplest thing to configure jenkins with code is to load groovy script on startup with the help of folder `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/`

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script